# How do I run lower() on a variable in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

The following works:

```
define schemaName = '&schema'
select
  table_name,
  column_name
from all_tab_columns
where lower(atc.owner) = '&schemaname'
```

How do I go about lowering the input parameter for `schema`? I've tried adding a second line of `define schemalow = lower(&schemaName)` but that ends up being `lower(sys)` assuming `sys` was entered by the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lower('&schemaname')`:

```
define schemaName = '&schema'
select
  table_name,
  column_name
from all_tab_columns
where lower(owner) = lower('&schemaname')
```

or change your second define to:

```
define schemalow = lower('&schemaname')
select
  atc.table_name,
  atc.column_name
from all_tab_columns atc
where lower(atc.owner) = &schemalow;
```

In the second version, the new define still has the quotes, in the appropriate place - they have to be around a substitution variable reference that has to be seen as a string literal. But note that the usage of that second substitution variable then does *not* have its own quotes.

Slightly simpler test, responding to the prompt with `sys`:

```
define schemalow = lower('&schemaname')
select count(*) from all_tab_columns atc
where lower(owner) = &schemalow;

  COUNT(*)
----------
     58842
```

---

Personally I'd probably use `upper()` in this case; but if you're having to worry about the case of the owner name that implies you have quoted identifiers - and that means that using upper/lower would hide any distinction between objects owned by, say, `"MYUSER"` and `"MyUser"`. Quoted identifiers should be avoided anyway, of course. And your real query may be against other tables where it makes more sense to do this and you've just used ATC as an example, in which case this aside is irrelevant...

Comment: Yeah I've done that but is there any way to do it on the input instead of doing that?

Comment: @simplycoding - Alex **did** "do it on the input". The point is, in what you tried, you should still use single quotes around `&schemaname` - you didn't which is why you got `lower(sys)` instead of `lower('sys')`.

Comment: @simplycoding - yes, I think I was updating it as you left your comment, but mathguy has summarised the important part....